# There is a problem when i'm trying to write data with csv.writer

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

```
import requests
import urllib as ulb
import re
import csv

temp= r"C:\Users\ATP\Desktop"+'\\'+"data"
with open(temp + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
    csvwriter.writerow(['ID', 'total', 'share', 'rate', 'employee', 'social', 'stake', 'environment'])
for i in range(1,184):
    url = (
        'http://stockdata.stock.hexun.com/zrbg/data/zrbList.aspx?date={}-12-31&count=20&pname=20&titType=null&page={}&callback=hxbase_json11571728040603'.format(
            2018, i))
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36'}
    req = ulb.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
    response = ulb.request.urlopen(req)
    html1 = response.read().decode('gbk')

    id = re.findall(r'(?<=\()\d\d\d\d\d\d(?=\))',html1)
    total = re.findall(r'(?<=industryrate:\').+?(?=\')',html1)
    share = re.findall(r'(?<=stockNumber:\').+?(?=\')',html1)
    rate = re.findall(r'(?<=Pricelimit:\').+?(?=\')',html1)      
    employee = re.findall(r'(?<=lootingchips:\').+?(?=\')',html1)

    social = re.findall(r'(?<=Strongstock:\').+?(?=\')',html1)

    stake = re.findall(r'(?<=Scramble:\').+?(?=\')',html1)
    environment = re.findall(r'(?<=rscramble:\').+?(?=\')',html1)  

    for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h in zip(id,total,share,rate,employee,social,stake,environment):

        with open(temp+'.csv','a',newline = '\n',encoding='gbk') as f:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(f,dialect='excel')
            csvwriter.writerow([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h])
```

The code is all above. And the problem is in variable 'social' which is the column 'social' in the csv file.
If I run 'print(social)', the data or the results could show as expected.
But when it is written in the csv file, the 'social' column displays  '**<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\ATP\Desktop\data.csv' mode='a' encoding='gbk'>**', rather than the data as expected.
Is there anyone knowing that how to fix this? Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HvY8.png)

Comment: f is also used as file pointer change the variable name and see in either for loop or when opening file for writing

Comment: After these variable names are changed, csvwriter.writerow(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']), like csvwriter.writerow(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh']), the problem still exists.  Besides, each time before I run the code, I will delete the csv file that already exists.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Since you are opening you file in append mode new entries might be in the bottom of the file

Comment: U r right about append mode. But I don't understand what's the relation with the error. I tried changing variable names, and deleting the csv file that alreay exists. And the problem is still not fixed. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Can you show your updated code and whats there in html1?

Comment: first you should use `print()` to check what you have in variables `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h`. Maybe you really create strings like `'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'` .

Comment: I don't understand why you use `regex`. You get response as JSON data which you can easily convert to python dictionary `data = dirtyjson.loads(html1[13:-1])` and then you can get data from this dictionary.

Comment: i run your code with different variable for open file and it save data in correct way so I don't see problem.

Comment: It is true that python does not report any error after running the code. But the data in csv is not right. I uploaded an image to show the problem just now. That's the result after running the code.

Comment: Oh my. The problem is caused by the repeat variable name. 'f' is used in different position in the code, and it's mixed up. Replace 'f' in the 'with open xxxx as f' line with other name that is not being used. The data will be written in correct way.

Comment: @excellent I already told you about the repeated f usage. Didn't I?

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the variable f in the for loop. 
Change the open statement to:

```py
with open(temp+'.csv','a',newline = '\n',encoding='gbk') as fp: # as f will override the f of the foor loop
```

and obviously change `csvwriter = csv.writer(f,dialect='excel')` to `csvwriter = csv.writer(fp,dialect='excel')`

Keep this mistake in mind to explain to yourself why it is very useful to type the extra characters and have meaningful variable names.